# Regex to match the string which contains dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a following regex:

```
[.][a-zA-Z]
```

So, if there's a string like `.row` then it will select `.r`. What I want is to be able to select only the dot i.e. regex selects only the dot(`.`)!

Comment: Did you try lookahead?

Comment: What's that? Anyway, let me check

Comment: Without more details: what part of capture group 2 in ((\.)][a-zA-Z]+) does not address this need? And more importantly, what are you [actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395686) trying to do, because just "finding the dot" in something like `.row` cannot possibly be the end of what you want to do. What are you trying to do that requires finding that dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```js
let str  = `.row`

console.log(str.match(/\.(?=[A-Za-z])/g))
```

Comment: @Sanjay sorry it was a typo. fixed

Comment: I tried this(`[\.][(?=[A-Za-z])]/g`) in VSCode find and replace. It didn't work

Comment: @Sanjay why are you putting positive lookahead in character class. use this `/\.(?=[A-Za-z])/`

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644846/how-to-append-something-in-a-string-separated-by-space-using-regex?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just select the dot, escape your `.` with `\.` since `.` means any single character. And don't include `[a-zA-Z]`

```
[\.]
```

https://regex101.com/r/mJ9A6u/1/

Comment: It will select the number too then

Comment: What number?? Please at least try to give us your input and expected output.